# Antlr 3 can't deal with syntactic predicate

Tags: java, syntax, antlr, predicate, antlr3

This problem has occurred to me many times.
I do not completely understand the problem fully.
My syntax looks like this:

```
grammar Syntax;

options {
  language = Java;
  backtrack = true;
}

rule: ('syntax' (INTEGER | HEX) ';')? (structure | packet)+;

structure: ('struct' | 'structure')? field;

packet: 'packet'? NAME '{' field+ '}';

field: NAME (':' | '=' | ':=' | '->')? value ';';

value: (TYPE (MULT (INTEGER | HEX))?);


MULT: 'x' | 'X';

INTEGER: ('0'..'9')+;

HEX: '0x' ('0'..'9' | 'A'..'F' | 'a'..'f');

TYPE: ('unsigned'? 'byte' | 'short' | 'int16' | 'int8')
    | 'int' | 'int32' 
    | 'long' | 'int64'
    | 'char' | 'char8' | 'char16' | 'unicode'
    | 'utf' | 'utf8' | 'utf16';

NAME: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*;

WHITESPACE: ( ' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f' | '\t')+{$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

The test-case looks like this:

```
syntax 1;
packet a
{
    a int;
    b byte;
    d byte x 10;
    c int x b;
}
```

Now the error is:

[image: errors]

Comment: TheBreadCat, I know next to nothing about antlr but this http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2009-February/033062.html suggests that maybe you're using the ANTLRworks interpreter rather than generating / compiling / running an actual parser, and the interpreter doesn't implement all the features of the language.

Comment: (It appears that `backtrack=true` is implemented by automatically inserting predicates.)

Comment: Gareth McCaughan, I'm using the built in interpreter in the eclipse plugin. But I'll try to do a real test case.

Comment: Probably the same interpreter as in ANTLRworks.

Comment: Alternatively, it shouldn't be terribly difficult to tweak your grammar to work without backtracking.

Comment: Actually it worked by just removing the backtrack = true!

Answer (score 3):

The interpreter of ANTLRWorks (which ANTLR Eclipse IDE also uses) cannot cope with predicates or embedded (Java) code. Enabling global backtracking<sup>1</sup> (which should be avoided, if possible!) causes **all** parser rules to get predicates in front of them (hence the error *"can't deal with predicates yet"*).

Besides, the interpreter is rather buggy: I don't recommend using it. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger, it's great and will also compile and run any embedded (Java) code in your grammar. I believe the ANTLR Eclipse IDE also has this debugger from ANTLRWorks.

<sup>1</sup> http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar